# Java declaring iterator outside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

According to the documentation of Oracle for loop is formed as we know it:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

E.g.,

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
}
```

Why can't we declare the initialization part outside the for loop like this?

```
 class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         int i = 1;
         for(i; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the 'i' in 'i;' and it should work.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to not mix problem statement and resolving it in the question post. Instead, you are allowed to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own question. Please, remove the answer part from your question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quoting Java Docs

*it's best to declare the variable in the initialization expression. The names i, j, and k are often used to control for loops; declaring them within the initialization expression limits their life span and reduces errors.
The three expressions of the for loop are optional; an infinite loop can be created as follows:*

```
// infinite loop
for ( ; ; ) {

    // your code goes here
}
```

So, I missed it. It is possible, however not favorable. Leaving initialization part blank is the solution

```
  for (  ;i <= 10 ; i++ ) {

        // i is defined outside already
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can with:

```
 for(; i<11; i++){
      System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
 }
```

But the scope of `i` is different. `i` will now exist outside of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can. However you would simply have a blank `;` in where the initialization usually goes:

```
int i = 1;
for(; i<11; i++){
    System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
}
```

The difference of this is that the scope of `i` is now broadened to outside of the loop. Which may be what you want. Otherwise it is best to keep variables to the tightest scope possible. As the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for the `for` loop say:

> declaring them within the initialization expression limits their life span and reduces errors.

**Output:**

```
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 5
Count is: 6
Count is: 7
Count is: 8
Count is: 9
Count is: 10
```

Answer (score 4):

What is really happening in the for loop that

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInit ; Expression; ForUpdate )
```

Initialization need a statment  as the docs says

> If the ForInit code is a list of statement expressions

[From Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14)

So in this code

```
 for(i; i<11; i++){ 
      System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
 }
```

`i` is not a statment, it is just a variable. So what is a statment?

> Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A
>   statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of
>   expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression
>   with a semicolon (;).
>
> ```
> Assignment expressions
> Any use of ++ or --
> Method invocations
> Object creation expressions
> ```

Whit this knowlodge you can work any for loop if you know what is statemnt for example this for loop works

```
int i = 1; // Initializated
for(i++; i<11; i++){ // Whit a statemnt
    System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
}
```

and the output will be :

```
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 5
Count is: 6
Count is: 7
Count is: 8
Count is: 9
Count is: 10
```